# T-SQL strange issue

Tags: asp.net, t-sql

I have a large T-SQL query (I only put a part here because I very sure the rest is working nice):

```
 WHERE /*
                ******* missing filter *******
                this line should filter the risks by @LoggedInPersonID via role 
                ******************************
          AND */(@PropertyID IS NULL OR p.PropertyID = @PropertyID)
          AND (@PCodePattern IS NULL OR p.PCode LIKE @PCodePattern)
          AND (@ZipCodeIDS IS NULL 
                 OR p.ZipCodeID IN (@ZipCodeIDS))
```

You notice that @ZipCodeIDS is a list... Well, I populate this from code with some ids. When @ZipCodeIDS contains a SINGLE id it works perfectly but if I try to send multiple ids (eg: "14,15") it gives me error....

Do you have any clue?

Ps: Of course I made @ZIpCodeIDS varchar because we do not have array in T-SQL...

UPDATE: If I directly hardcode in the query: `IN (14,11)` it perfectly works... so somehow I do not correctly send this parameter from my code for multiple values I think it does not see "," as a separator...

**UPDATE 2**: Tried to split the lists and put the ids into a table... When zipCodeIDS has only one id the query works perfectly. For multiple ones, not... Do you see something strange on ELSE?

```
    IF @ZipCodeIDS IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    IF CHARINDEX(',', @ZipCodeIDS) = 0
    BEGIN
        insert @listofIDS values(@ZipCodeIDS)
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        WHILE CHARINDEX(',', @ZipCodeIDS) != 0
        BEGIN
            insert @listofIDS values(Left(@ZipCodeIDS, PatIndex(',', @ZipCodeIDS) - 1))
            SET @ZipCodeIDS = SUBSTRING(@ZipCodeIDS, CHARINDEX(',',@ZipCodeIDS)+1, LEN(@ZipCodeIDS) - CHARINDEX(',',@ZipCodeIDS))
        END
    END
END
```

Comment: You could just print out the query to see what it actually looks like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Declare @listofIDS table(zipcodeids varchar(10))

Declare @ZipCodeIDS varchar(100)
set  @ZipCodeIDS= '14,15'

set @ZipCodeIDS+= ','
;with cte as
(
select substring(@ZipCodeIDS, 1, charindex(',', @ZipCodeIDS) - 1) num, charindex(',', @ZipCodeIDS) pos
union all
select substring(@ZipCodeIDS, pos + 1, charindex(',', @ZipCodeIDS, pos +1) - pos - 1) num, charindex(',', @ZipCodeIDS, pos +1)
from cte
where charindex(',', @ZipCodeIDS, pos +1) > 0

)
INSERT @listofIDS 
select num from cte


.... or p.ZipCodeID in (select zipcodeids from @listofIDS) 

--------------------
```

Try this (remember to set all your variables):

```
Declare @ZipCodeIDS varchar(100)
set  @ZipCodeIDS= '14,15'

set @ZipCodeIDS+= ','
;with cte as
(
select cast(substring(@ZipCodeIDS, 1, charindex(',', @ZipCodeIDS) - 1) as int) num, charindex(',', @ZipCodeIDS) pos
union all
select cast(substring(@ZipCodeIDS, pos + 1, charindex(',', @ZipCodeIDS, pos +1) - pos - 1) as int) num, charindex(',', @ZipCodeIDS, pos +1)
from cte
where charindex(',', @ZipCodeIDS, pos +1) > 0
)

SELECT /*... rest of your query that was not included in the question. no colon, nor anything else, just your query plus the small alteration i made in the end
...
...*/
WHERE /*
                ******* missing filter *******
                this line should filter the risks by @LoggedInPersonID via role 
                ******************************
          AND */(@PropertyID IS NULL OR p.PropertyID = @PropertyID)
          AND (@PCodePattern IS NULL OR p.PCode LIKE @PCodePattern)
          AND (@ZipCodeIDS IS NULL 
                 OR p.ZipCodeID IN (select num from cte))
```

Comment: Seems interesting the solution with the table..but please keep in mind that I can have N ids...is there a way to insert n values?

Comment: Yes, I made a recusive sql to split your text into several id's and populate the temporary table with them

Comment: Do you know, is there a way to see this temp table values? Seems that even with your code is not working and I wanted to make sure that it correctly puts splited values into the table...

Comment: Can you please see my UPDATE 2? This is what I wrote myself and it works for list with one id. but for multiple ids it failes...Do you see a problem?

Comment: you can test my code here http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/109362/ it works just fine

Comment: It says: "Error: Incorrect syntax near ')'." at the end..

Comment: Your code fails because you changed charindex to patindex. Patindex has another syntax.

Comment: @CristianBoariu let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2431/discussion-between-t-clausen-dk-and-cristian-boariu)

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at this article -

http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql.html

It discusses a number of ways you could alter your query.

This question may also prove helpful -

[Parameterize an SQL IN clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337704/parameterizing-a-sql-in-clause)

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `IN` like that. It's trying to look for p.ZipCodeID where the zip code is equal to '14, 15', in your example.

Instead, you'll have to compare p.ZipCodeID to *each* zip code you need, e.g.

```
... OR p.ZipCodeID=14 OR p.ZipCodeID=15
```

The alternative (which is less preferable) is to dynamically generate the SQL statement and then use `EXEC` to run it. The main problem with that, of course, is SQL injection.

Comment: Yeah, but because I have N zip codes id, I cannot use it like this....do you know any other work-around?

Comment: Isn't `p.ZipCodeID=14 OR p.ZipCodeID=15` equivalent to `p.ZipCodeID IN (14, 15)`?

Comment: I do kindly ask for a link or example on how to do this dynamically as you said...

Comment: @NullUserException Yes, except that when you use parameters, it converts the parameter to, in this case, a string, so the parser actually sees `p.ZipCodeID IN ('14,15')` which is _not_ the same as the `OR` clause used in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Can you do `DECLARE @ZipCodeIDS TABLE(id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY)` and then join this table?

Comment: Well, I already have that table...and I do join of course based on which ids from that table user has selected...using checkboxes..

Answer (score 0):

```
 AND (@ZipCodeIDS IS NULL OR p.ZipCodeID IN (select z.ID from @ZipCodeIDS))
```

You state that SQL has no "array" but everything works in sets.  Create a temporary table or a table variable and fill it with your zipcodeIDs

```
declare @ZipCodeIDs = TABLE ( ID int NOT NULL)
```

fill @ZipCodeIDs with the ints

then use your code as before

If you are trying to pass an array from your .net code to the databaes you can do this with a user defined table type in SQL server 2008.